# two dimensional array assigning beyond row length?

Tags: arrays, c, linked-list

I am currently working with a linked list and am converting certain elements into character arrays, and i do this by checking whether or not we have reached a newline character (10) when traversing the linked list. the purpose of this is so that i can identify distinct groupings of characters, linearly searching the array.
However, when i test this by printing a row, it appears to write (continually smaller) sections of the entire linked list to the row in the for loop, despite this often exceeding the allocated size of such a row. (cur max is often small, and linked list is often large). I feel like this may be a logic error but i cant see it right now... also it doesnt add the \0 when it should, only on the last row.
important background: i add to the list by foot only, and use the head to traverse (dunno if this would have any impact.)

here is the code for array creation:

```
    //traces are just character arrays. cur max is the max length of a trace. 
    char arr_all_traces[total_trace_count][cur_max];
    // run through the linked list again and add to the array.
     temp = current_trace.head;
     
     for (int i = 0; i < total_trace_count; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j <= cur_max; j++) {
             if (temp->actn == 10 || j == cur_max) { 
                  arr_all_traces[i][cur_max] = '\0';
                  temp = temp->next;  
                  j = 0;
                  break;
             }
             if (temp->actn != 10 && temp != NULL){
                 arr_all_traces[i][j] = temp->actn;
                 temp = temp->next;  
             }
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your inner loop, you're using a comparison `j <= cur_max`, not `j < cur_max`. This results in you overrunning your inner loop by one place.

This is compounded by the line `arr_all_traces[i][cur_max] = '\0';`, which forcibly oversteps the end of the row, even if you fixed the condition for `j`.

This may not immediately become obvious, as you're within the allocated memory until the outer loop's final iteration. At that point, you will write one beyond the end of your `arr_all_traces[][]` array, potentially causing a segmentation fault, or at least corrupting memory somewhere nearby.

The solution is probably to make the declaration  `char arr_all_traces[total_trace_count][cur_max+1];` (note the "+1"), ensuring you're safe from overrun.

By the way, you'd be better off comparing against `'\n'` than `10`, since this makes your intent more clear.